# Error message : load denied X-Frame-Options

Tags: java, javascript, iframe, error-handling, x-frame-options

I am trying to load google calender into an iframe in my application. When i am logged into gmail i can access the google calender. However if i i am not logged into my gmail there is an error in the console 
    `Load denied by X-Frame-Options:`+ the src + `does not permit framing` 
What i want is when this error comes up i want an error message shown to the user which reminds them to log into their gmail before accessing the feature.

How to catch the error  ?

Here is my iframe

```
`var link = "<iframe id='test' src=\"https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src="+ gmail +"&amp;color=%232952A3&amp;ctz=Asia%2FKuala_Lumpur\"" 
+ "style=\" border-width:0 \""
+ "width=\"100%\"" 
+ "height=\"600\"" 
+ "frameborder=\"0\"" 
+ "scrolling=\"no\""
+ "onload=\"chk(this)\"></iframe>";
`
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting this error, you need to add `&output=embed` to the **source link**.